# React native share image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to share an image, either taken from camera or from gallery, to other devices through various available device's application's(eg whatsApp, skype, email etc.)
I found the "Share" function provided but as per my knowledge and research, it only allows to share text data.

Has someone have any idea for sharing an image through a react native application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share

Comment: Thanks @ParasWatts .. working :)

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/60905965/5079876 -> Please check out this answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 17):

Solution:

- Get the path of the image to convert base64.
- For share image use: react-native-share [lib share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share)
- To access the device directories, I recommend using: rn-fetch-blob.
  [Wikki lib](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API)

  ```
    dwFile(file_url) {
        let imagePath = null;
        RNFetchBlob.config({
            fileCache: true
        })
        .fetch("GET", file_url)
        // the image is now dowloaded to device's storage
        .then(resp => {
            // the image path you can use it directly with Image component
            imagePath = resp.path();
            return resp.readFile("base64");
        })
        .then(async base64Data => {
            var base64Data = `data:image/png;base64,` + base64Data;
            // here's base64 encoded image
            await Share.open({ url: base64Data });
            // remove the file from storage
            return fs.unlink(imagePath);
        });
    }
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very nice solution! Just made some following minor changes on my system - 

"fs.unlink(imagePath)" to "RNFetchBlob.fs.unlink(imagePath)"

Comment: Thanks! The piece I was missing here was "data:image/png;base64," prefix for the base64 image value.

Answer (score 4):

You can also send the image with Share through the `url` parameter:

`url: "data:image/png;base64,<base64_data>"`
Cheers

Comment: Reading the documentation, it seems that "url" only work on ios.

Comment: Hey @Juanan Jimenez , Its not working for me can you please make sure either its working or not on android

Answer (score 4):

Since Expo's SDK33, you can use Expo Sharing to share any type of file to other apps that can handle its file type even if you're on Android. Without detaching or anything.

See https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/

Usage is pretty simple:

```
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing'; // Import the library

Sharing.shareAsync(url) // And share your file !
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried as following:

```
import {
     Share
} from 'react-native';
 let shareImage = {
                title: caption,//string
                message: message,//string
                url:imageUrl,// eg.'http://img.gemejo.com/product/8c/099/cf53b3a6008136ef0882197d5f5.jpg',

            };
            Share.open(shareImage).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Hope this will help you.Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't work on Android and its documentation says url prop is available only for iOS

Answer (score 1):

I used `react-native-share` plugin to do the same

Steps :

1. npm install react-native-share --save
2. react-native link

Read [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) for rest of the code ...its very easy and straight forward. 
If you want to share image in `base64` u have to pass like this :

`"data:image/png;base64,BASE STRING"`

And If you want to share directly from source you have to pass like this :

`url: "file://<file_path>",`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share both image and url simultaneously on most of the social media or platform. To do so, you will need a sharable image link that is can be created by API.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Share.share({
      message: "dummy text",
      url:"https://xyz.jpg"
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
```

Try this code, this should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: your code shares only text

Answer (score 0):

Fresh answer from 2022 :) Example with screenshot.
Btw, parameter url works in Android

```
import ViewShot,{captureScreen} from 'react-native-view-shot';
import Share from 'react-native-share';

<Pressable onPress={()=>{
              captureScreen({format: "jpg",quality: 0.8,
                }).then((uri) => { ShareScreenShot(uri); },
                (error) => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error));}} >

const ShareScreenShot = async (urifile) => {
  Share.open({message:'Result', url:urifile}) .then((res) => {
    //console.log(res);
  }) .catch((err) => {
    /*err && */console.log('error', err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For React Native iOS apps, you can share an image by specifying the image url (as per the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share)). For example:

```
 const onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message: "Check out this item!",
        url: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Funny_black_lab_mix_dog%27s_look.jpg` // this is the image url!
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };
```