# How to share a image using react native share api

Tags: react-native

I want to share a image in my app. I am currently working with the react native share api. But i can onlu share a message  or url only. How can share a image using react native share api.

My code

```
 _onpress = () => {
Share.share({
  message: "this is a image"
}).then(this.showresult());
```

};

insted of a message how can i send a image

Comment: Are you using this API `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html`? Then you can only share `text content` as the API describe.

Comment: ya.then how can   send a image

Comment: try this `https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share`

Comment: in that is i have to implement the share options.I mean when using share api it takes the mobile share options and display in pop up.(whatsus , viber , mesenger ...etc)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295905/react-native-share-image.