# react native image is not displaying while sharing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native-share` to share image but when I try to share image it's not displaying(image shown below). Also when I click send image not even text was send. Can anyone tell me why?

That's my code

```
  const onShare = () => {
    Share.open({
      message: 'Hello',
      url: 'data:image/png;base64,https://cdn.logo.com/hotlink-ok/logo-social-sq.png',
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        err && console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Is the image actually base64?

Comment: I just read about that and it's not. Can't we do this with http link?

Comment: you may need to encode it as base64 first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295905/react-native-share-image

Comment: ah nevermind, I see you have a remote image url. You should be able to just remove `'data:image/png;base64,` from your code